# How to store instance in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, pixi.js

There is one Pixi instance available. I want to keep it in vuex but I have problems even if I use JSON.stringfy. I want to create an instance and use it everywhere in the vue project.

Comment: ". I want to keep it in vuex but I have problems even if I use JSON.stringfy" - what did you try? This is potential XY problem. You don't need Vuex to use singletons

Comment: I want to create an instance and use it on any page I want. how do I do this?

Comment: A separate module with `export let pixi; export function createPixi() { pixi = new Application() }`. Import `pixi` anywhere. This is common JS that is not specific to Vue. It can cause more problems than solve to store complex objects in Vuex because they may not work well with Vue reactivity

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you are looking for, so apologies if I'm way off.

To store something in vuex, you generally [call an action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) which then [calls a mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) which will update your vuex store.

So to provide a really simple example, that might look something like this:

```
// Page.vue


<template>...</template>
<script>
    computed: {
        pixi() {
            return this.$store.getters['pixi/pixi'];  // get from vuex
        }
    }
    ...

    methods: {
        async setPixi(payload) {
            await this.$store.dispatch('pixi/setPixi', payload);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my example above, I am assuming that you are breaking your vuex store out into modules. That's what the `dispatch('pixi/setPixi'...)` is doing.

That means you might have a directory structure like this:

```
store
  |- modules
        |- pixi.js
  |- index.js
```

Your `index.js` file would look like:

```
// index.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import * as pixi from '@/store/modules/pixi';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    getters: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {
        pixi,
    },
});
```

Then your `pixi.js` store might look like this:

```
// pixi.js

export const namespaced = true;

export const state = {
    pixi: undefined,
};

export const mutations = {
    SET_PIXI(state, payload) {
        state.pixi = payload;
    },
};

export const actions = {
    setPixi({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('SET_PIXI', payload);
    },
}

export const getters = {
   pixi: (state) => {
        return state.pixi;
    },
}
```

Then you'd use a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) to return the pixi value from your store (example above).

Hope this helps get you going...